# Django logging fails because of wrong system Locale

Tags: python, django, locale

I have a Django app, which fails to log with the error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character`.  The problem is that the system locale is the CentOS default locale, which is ASCII. The admins don't want to change the system-wide locale on their servers, saying that the apps should be able to run in a clean environment.

We circumvented the problem for the Django apps themselves by adding this to the uwsgi.ini:

```
env = LANG=en_US.UTF-8
env = LANGUAGE=en_US.en
env = LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

However, uwsgi.ini has no effect on the code run as a django management command, and we have a lot of work done in those.

What could be the best way to fix that?

**UPD**: We also tried setting the locale in the `settings.py` file, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the default encoding in the `sitecustomize.py` module inside the `site-packages` folder of your Python distribution. This module is [loaded by Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) when it starts up and arbitrary site-specific customizations can be placed in here.

**sitecustomize.py**

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
```

You may need to create the module if it doesn't already exist.